# Protecting user passwords in desktop applications

Tags: twitter, passwords, hash

I'm making a twitter client, and I'm evaluating the various ways of protecting the user's login information.

- Hashing apparently doesn't do it
- Obfuscating in a reversable way is like trying to hide behind my finger
- Plain text sounds and propably is promiscuous
- Requiring the user to type in his password every time would make the application tiresome

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why exactly doesn't hashing do it?

Comment: Because once you've hashed the password, you can't recover it in order to use it to log on. This is a client. Password hashing is a technique for servers.

Comment: The site's UI makes it kinda hard to provide details on the problem,but:
What I didn't expain is that I'm looking to protect the user's data from other applications also running under the same privileges.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make some OS calls to encrypt the password for you.

On Windows:

- You can encrypt a file (on a NTFS filesystem)
- Use the [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) from C
- Use the DPAPI in .Net by using the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

What platform?

On *nix, store the password in plain text in a file chmoded 400 in a subdirectory of the home directory. See for example ~/.subversion. Administrators can do anything they like to users anyway, including replacing your program with their own hacked version that captures passwords, so there's no harm in the fact that they can see the file. Beware that the password is also accessible to someone who takes out that hard drive - if this is a problem then either get the user to reenter the password each time or check whether this version of *nix has file encryption.

On Windows Pro, store the password in an encrypted file.

On Windows Amateur, do the same as *nix. [Edit: CryptProtectData looks good, as Aleris suggests. If it's available on all Windowses, then it solves the problem of only the more expensive versions supporting encrypted files].

On Symbian, store the password in your data cage. Programs with AllFiles permission are rare and supposedly trusted anyway, a bit like *nix admins.

Answer (score 1):

CryptProtectData is a windows function for storing this kind of sensitive data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261.aspx

For an example see how Chrome uses it:
http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2008/09/10/how-google-chrome-stores-passwords/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows: encrypt the password using DPAPI (user store) and store it in your  settings file or somewhere else. This will work on a per-user basis, e.g. different users on the same  machine will have different unrelated encryption keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your cake and eat it too. Either store the password (which you've ruled out), or don't and require it to be typed in every time (which you've ruled out.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a good symmetric encryption scheme, it should make it difficult enough to decrypt the credentials that it won't worth trying. 
Otherwise, if the service only requires the hash to be sent over the network, you can store the hast encrypted. This way even the decryption won't get the attacker closer to the solution.
However other users are true. If you store the data it can be found. 
The key is finding the balance between security and usability.

Comment: A good symmetric encryption scheme just replaces the password problem with a key problem. If the service takes a hash over the network, then it's as good as a password.